# app icon don't change

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, icons

i've upload an icon to app in dev area on facebook, but in post that created via app i see another icon 
 http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=342798179094087&v=1&size=z&cksum=418d0035bf803448240c46f206d53fac&src=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FbFTnqd

but in my icon shows monkey not "214 apps", and i check an app id it is right.
please help me.
p.s. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your icon gets overridden by another image in your meta tags. you can check them easily [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: i dont add meta tags, i create post via objective c FbGraph. in your url i haven't seen some overriddes

Comment: what are your og: data? what is the source of that "monkey" image?

Comment: in my dev area source of img is https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/photos-ak-snc1/v85006/87/342798179094087/app_1_342798179094087_1673.gif  but i thought when i upload an image in dev area image should upadte in my created via app post, or not?

Comment: as I said the post data can be overridden by meta tags to customize the posts like text, title, ... you can see the actual og: data in your document head or use the link posted above. 

if the monkey icon is your old icon, it may be cached by facebook. you can lint it using the debugger, too.

Comment: i check that url http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=342798179094087&v=1&size=z&cksum=418d0035bf803448240c46f206d53fac&src=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FbFTnqd in debugger and it have not og:data only og:title,og:type,og:url,og:updated_time

Comment: is the monkey image the one you uploaded before? is your new icon visible in your app settings?

Comment: which image url do you get here: https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_ID?fields=icon_url

Comment: monkey is new image, is the first image i was upload, in app settings it show monkey icon

Comment: if you want this icon: http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=342798179094087&v=1&size=z&cksum=418d0035bf803448240c46f206d53fac&src=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FbFTnqd instead of the previously uploaded monkey icon and it is not visible in your settings, your upload may have failed. am I right that you uploaded the monkey icon at first and want the other one now?

Comment: i found my mistake, image what i want to change was the image from link not the logo. thank you for help.